# How to create a cable bending animation?

Tags: modeling, animation

friends, I’m a newbie in Blender. I’m trying to create a similar bending wire animation in Blender. I don’t know how to achieve it. Is there a special technique to accomplish it?[image]

Comment: You Can Use A Curve To Bend Them. Or A Bone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create Armature ...

[image]

... and use Bendy Bones type to deform object ... ?

[image]

[image]

For a wire you can use a Curve object type Bezier. Add control points in place of bones connections. Under Curve Properties > Geometry, Bevel > Depth set thickness of wire.

[image]

For inner handles of curved parts set type <kbd>V</kbd> Free (they became colored red).

[image]